# ILU0 factorization with Python scipy spilu function

Tags: python

I am trying to use scipy spilu function to ILU0 factorize a matrix in csc format. However, I don't see any option that allows me to use zero fill-in as fill_factor >= 1.0 and always performs fill in. Can someone guide me about this?

I have tried spilu(A, fill_factor=1.0). Still gives some fill in

LU = linalg.spilu(mat_csc)